# How to place select element and toggle button to free jqgrid toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm looking for a way to place select element and toggle button to free jqgrid top toolbar if font awesome icon set is used.
I tried code which worked in 4.6:

```
    var i,
        selectElem= '<select tabindex="-1" id="_layout">';

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        selectElem += '<option value="'+i+'" ';
        if (i==layout)
            selectElem += ' selected';
        selectElem += '>Form ' + i + '</option>'
    }

    $("#grid_toppager_left table.navtable tbody tr").append(
           '<td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all">' +
           '<div class="ui-pg-div my-nav-checkbox">' +
           selectElem +
           '</select>' +
           '</div></td>'
           );
```

but select element does not appear.

For toggle button I tried

```
    $("#grid_toppager_left table.navtable tbody tr").append(
           '<td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all">' +
               '<div class="ui-pg-div my-nav-checkbox">' +
               '<input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" id="AutoEdit" ' + (autoedit ? 'checked ' : '')+'/>' +
               '<label ' +' for="AutoEdit">Toggle</label></div></td>'
                      );
    $("#AutoEdit").button({
        text: false,
        icons: {primary: "fa-star"}
    }).click(function () {
            autoedit = !autoedit;
        }
    });
```

but toggle button also does not appear in toolbar.
How to force those elements to appear ?

Comment: I wrote **UPDATED** part with alternative solution of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change because `.navtable` is now **not table**. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Redesign-of-the-structure-of-Navigator-Bar-of-the-pagers) for more details. So the code should be something like the following:

```js
$("#grid_toppager_left .navtable").append(
 '<div class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all">' +
     '<div class="ui-pg-div my-nav-checkbox">' +
     '<input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" id="AutoEdit" ' + (autoedit ? 'checked ' : '')+'/>' +
     '<label ' +' for="AutoEdit">Toggle</label></div></div>'
            );
$("#AutoEdit").button({
    text: false,
    icons: {primary: "fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-star"}
}).click(function () {
        autoedit = !autoedit;
    }
);
var $label = $("#AutoEdit").next("label");
$label.children(".ui-button-icon-primary").removeClass("ui-icon");
$label.find(".ui-button-text").hide();
```

Additionally I added small CSS fixes

```js
.my-nav-checkbox > .ui-button-icon-only { margin-top: 5px; }
.my-nav-checkbox > .ui-button-icon-only > .ui-button-icon-primary.fa { margin-left: 6px; }
.my-nav-checkbox:hover  { margin: 1px;  }
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tougleButton.htm) shows the results:

[image]

**UPDATED:** I though more about your question and I can suggest better solution of the same problem. I think that it would be easier don't use jQuery UI Button at all. instead of that one can mark the button as "checked" just by toggling `ui-state-active` class. So I suggest to add the CSS rule

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active { margin: 1px; }
```

first of all. The implementation of the checked button one can make by using `navButtonAdd` method:

```js
var autoedit = false;
$grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
    buttonicon: "fa-star",
    caption: "",
    id: "AutoEdit",
    title: "Toggle autoedit",
    onClickButton: function (options, e) {
        autoedit = !autoedit;
        //$("#"+options.id)[autoedit ? "addClass" : "removeClass"]("ui-state-active");
        $(e.currentTarget)[autoedit ? "addClass" : "removeClass"]("ui-state-active");
    }
});
```

[The corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/tougleButton1.htm) seems to work without any side effects and be very simple. The displayed results of "checked" button look like on the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Great. How to place select element to toolbar in similar way? Question contains code which creates 10 elements which can be numeric buttons with captions 1..10 Can this method extended to create button which can have values 1..10 like bootstrap combo button ? Or should append() with ugly markup string used to create select as earlier ?

Comment: In updated answer, if code is changed to `var autoedit = true;`  button is initially in unchecked state. How to put button initially to checked state? Former answer shows button initially in checked state in this case

Comment: @Andrus: The simplest way to create checked button will be to use `id: "AutoEdit"` and to add `$("#AutoEdit").click();` directly after the call of `navButtonAdd`. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/tougleButton1_.htm)

Comment: @Andrus: The question with select element seems be *new question*. Could you formulate it separately and describe with more details: how should looks like input data for the select? Is there close examples which uses jQuery UI for example? Do you need probably just include button which create context menu on click on the button?

Comment: In last demo in answer try to over mouse cursor between add new row and edit row buttons in Chrome. Icon sizes are changing and this causes whole toolbar dancing effect. If toobar wraps to multiple lines this effect can cause last button from one row to jump to next row on mouse hover. How to fix it ? Also `.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active { margin: 1px; }` didnt have any effect to added button in my application.

Comment: @Andrus: Chrome is my main web browser and I can't see any problem **if zoom is 100% or 200%**. If one use other zoom then there are small hovering effects on standard navigator buttons. The effects exist in all versions of jqGrid. New toggle button have absolutely the same behavior in my tests. I don't changed *the whole structure* of navigator buttons in free jqGrid to have more backwards compatibility with 4.6/4.7. So I don't see any simple way to eliminate all hovering effects of buttons in case of zoom not equal 100% or 200%.

Comment: Dancing video in Chrome is at https://youtu.be/zuIlKfDuGog  free jqGrid wraps buttons to multiple lines so this is more ugly in free jqgrid. For regular buttons dancing is remved using `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pg-div > span {
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
` Style in answer does not remove it from pressed toggle button. How to remove it from pressed toggle button also? middle part of toolbar is removed using `#grid_toppager_center {
    width: 0;
}
`

Comment: It occurs in Chrome and in Internet Explorer at 100% zoom level.

Comment: The video shows that you use **absolutely another settings** with icons over the text. Moreover you used another `margin` and `font-size`. I think that in the case one can use another CSS rule to fix the code.

Comment: @Andrus: I tested the case `iconsOverText: true`. One need to set `font-weight: normal;` additionally. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/tougleButton1_iconOver.htm). It has no problems in my tests for zoom 100% or 200%.